# Python - pd.to_datetime does not convert object string to datetime, keeps being object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

following problem:
I'm trying to convert a column of a DataFrame from a string to a datetime object with following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Time (CET)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (CET)'])
```

Should be the standard pandas way to do so. But the dtype of the column doesn't change, keeps being an object while no error or exception is raised.

The entries look like `2018-12-31 17:47:14+01:00`.

If I apply `pd.to_datetime` with `utc=True`, it works completely fine, dtype changes from `object` to `datetime64[ns, UTC]`. Unfortunately I don't want to convert the time to UTC, only converting the string to a datetime object without any time zone changes.

Thanks a lot!